# How to get NodeSet for evaluate() method of XPathExpression - for saxon 9.3 lib

Tags: xslt, saxon

i am using saxon lib 9.3 for XPath evluation

following code returns List of TinyElementImpl instances -

```
 XPathEvaluator evaluator = new XPathEvaluator();
 XPathExpression exp = evaluator.createExpression("//a[matches(.,'#...#')]");
 List<Object> result = exp.evaluate(domSource);
```

Previous versions supported evaluate method like to return a NodeSet

```
 exp.evaluate(domSource,XPathConstants.NODESET)
```

Is there any equivalent in the saxon 9.3 lib?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missed this question. If you want to be sure of getting an answer to a Saxon question, ask on the saxon-help mailing list or forum at SourceForge.

If your XPathEvaluator is a net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator then this method is still present in 9.3. Perhaps you've instantiated a net.sf.saxon.sxpath.XPathEvaluator by mistake?

Another confusion here is that I would imagine domSource is an instance of DOMSource, but it that's the case then I would expect the result to include DOM nodes rather than Saxon TinyTree nodes. The difficulty here is that you haven't shown enough of your code.

If you want to get the best results out of Saxon's XPath processor, I would recommend using the s9api interface rather than the JAXP interface, which is awfully focussed on DOM and XPath 1.0.